# Transparentize some bars of dataset in ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I am using ChartJS bar chart to show sales data for the year that has both - data for past months and data for upcoming months of the year. What i would like to do is to show the past months data in solid blue bars and for upcoming months, I would like to transparentize the blue to 50%. This is just to indicate that the coming months data are an estimate and not actual sales. Appreciate if someone can give me any pointers.

Comment: Please share some reproducible code or sample fiddle so that we can refer to it and give you better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the [`backgoundColor`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#styling) as an `array` of colors created with the [`rgba()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgba()) function. The forth parameter of `rgba()` defines the transparency.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [2, 5, 3, 4],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)']
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="120"></canvas>
```

> Note that instead of `rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)`, you can also simply use [`rgb(54, 162, 235)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/rgb()) to represent the solid blue color.